# Overflow hidden if text length increases jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K655K/) first hand!.

What i have is a div with a string. Now whenever i `hover` the `.dots` it makes its text inside `bolder` which increases its `length` or `size` . I want something like if the text size increases then it should not dissapear like `overflow:hidden` but show appear followed by `3 dots`. for example look at this image........

[image: 1]

since the name is too long it appears followed be `dots`. How can i possibly do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very easy solution.
Just add this to your .dots css :

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

So your css looks like this:

```
.dots {
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
    color:#333;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K655K/4/) i made.

Answer (score 3):

Try `text-overflow:ellipsis;` and `white-space:nowrap`

```
.dots {
 height:20px;
 width:150px;
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid #DDD;
 color:#333;
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:2px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/K655K/1/

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css class:

```
    .dots {
          .....
        overflow:hidden;
        padding:2px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis; // required
        white-space: nowrap; // required
    }
```